# 'pod install' command Not Working (trunk Repo update failed)

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I am facing an issue while running the 'pod install' command in Flutter projects.

when I run fady@Fadys-MacBook-Pro ios % `pod install`

the output:

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CDN: trunk Repo update failed - 9 error(s):
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/1.12.1303/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/1.17.0/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/1.22.4/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/1.9.102/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/2.0.0/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/2.10.2/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/2.2.2/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/2.5/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/3.0.0/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error

[!] `<XCBuildConfiguration name=`Debug` UUID=`331C8088294A63A400263BE5`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `AE0B7B92F70575B8D7E0D07E` for attribute: `base_configuration_reference`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<XCBuildConfiguration name=`Release` UUID=`331C8089294A63A400263BE5`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `89B67EB44CE7B6631473024E` for attribute: `base_configuration_reference`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<XCBuildConfiguration name=`Profile` UUID=`331C808A294A63A400263BE5`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `640959BDD8F10B91D80A66BE` for attribute: `base_configuration_reference`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXNativeTarget name=`RunnerTests` UUID=`331C8080294A63A400263BE5`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `331C807E294A63A400263BE5` for attribute: `build_phases`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.
```

I tried to uninstall and install cocoapods many times but still not working

**ruby vesios => ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [arm64-darwin22]**

**pod version: 1.12.1**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 13.4 22F66 darwin-arm64, locale en-EG)
    ! Warning: `flutter` on your path resolves to /Users/fadyfouad/flutter/bin/flutter, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/fadyfouad/Flutter.
      Consider adding /Users/fadyfouad/Flutter/bin to the front of your path.
    ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to /Users/fadyfouad/flutter/bin/dart, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/fadyfouad/Flutter.
      Consider adding /Users/fadyfouad/Flutter/bin to the front of your path.
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.3.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.79.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue to yours, your error says `SSL connect error` so I'm assuming it could be a problem with vpn. I installed warp vpn and it worked for a while then it stopped working , have you managed to find a solution to your issue?